# Storing return values in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, reverse, let

```
 (define (odds lst)
    (if (null? lst)
      lst
      (cons (car lst)
            (if (or (null? lst)
                    (not (pair? (cdr lst))))
              '()
              (odds (cddr lst)))))
      )
```

This function returns the *odd-numbered* elements; my issue is, I want to take the list it returns and reverse it (using the built in `reverse` function). I've been trying to use `lambda` to store it but the results don't change, also tried using `set-cons!` also, to no avail. The concept of using `let` in a recursive function seems to escape me. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If `(odds '(1 2 3 4))` outputs `'(1 3)`, then its reverse would be `(reverse (odds '(1 2 3 4)))`, output being `'(3 1)`.

Comment: But assuming `odds` is supposed to return the odd numbers in a list, it doesn't work as you expect it. For example, `(odds '(1 3 5 7 9))` outputs `'(1 5 9)`, even though all elements of that list are odd.

Comment: @assefamaru It's the odd-indexed elements of a list, starting at 1.

Comment: You can remove the second `(null? lst)`, it's never true, and thus get rid of `or`, as only its second argument remains.

Comment: "I've been trying to use `lambda` to store it" how? "but the results don't change," show us! "also tried using `set-cons!` also, to no avail." show us the code! Without seeing your code, we're forced to shooting in the dark, which isn't very productive, and not as helpful *to you* as well. It is in *your* interest to ask question properly, including all relevant code and test calls with it, and their actual and expected outcome. to ask otherwise, is not especially *courteous*.

Comment: is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49723995/scheme-function-that-returns-the-odd-numbered-elements-from-a-list-in-reverse) what you mean? please respond.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet storing both the return and the result using let*

```
(define (odds lst)    
  (if(null? lst)
    lst
    (cons (car lst)
       (if (or (null? lst)
               (not(pair? (cdr lst))))
       '()
        (odds (cddr lst))))))

(define data (odds `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) ) )

(let ((rev_odds ( reverse data  )))
   ;do stuff with results
   (display rev_odds)
     )
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you had those numbers? By odd number, I meant the indices. Would I use let* to store the final list made by cons and then use reverse? I just need the result of my function to be reversed. Thanks.

Comment: I chose them because they represent the indices. Also you can just use let, not let*, see the change above.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function's result to `reverse` in the place where you want the reversed list:

```
> (odds '(a b c d e))
'(a c e)
> (reverse (odds '(a b c d e)))
'(e c a)
> (let ((o (reverse (odds '(a b c d e))))) (append o o))
'(e c a e c a)
> (define (reverse-odds ls) (reverse (odds ls)))
> (reverse-odds '(5 6 a 9 "hi"))
'("hi" a 5)
```

Comment: I'm confused by the third line and on. Can I do that within the function itself? As in can I put that let within the function and when I call my odd function it does it's job AND reverses the list?

Comment: These use the function you defined. If you want a function that returns the reverse of the odd-indexed elements, use two functions (like `reverse-odds` above).

Answer (score 0):

You can skip worrying about a return value if you just `cons` directly onto the recursive result

```
(define (odds lst)
  (if (null? lst)
    null
    (if (odd? (car lst))
        (cons (car lst)
              (odds (cdr lst)))
        (odds (cdr lst)))))

(odds '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; => '(1 3 5 7)
```

One way to represent a "return" value is by adding a parameter to our recursive function. Below we use `acc` in our auxiliary helper function, `loop`. Usage of parameters like this is one common way to move the recursive call into [*tail position*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

```
(define (odds lst)
  (define (loop acc lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        (reverse acc)
        (if (odd? (car lst))
            (loop (cons (car lst) acc)
                  (cdr lst))
            (loop acc
                  (cdr lst)))))
  (loop null lst))

(odds '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; => '(1 3 5 7)
```

Another way is to represent our return value is by way of a lambda, `cont` below. We simply call `cont` with the value we wish to return. The recursive call looks a little more complicated in this case as we have to construct a lambda that represents the *new* return value. The added benefit here is `odds` constructs the result in order; `reverse` is no longer necessary

```
(define (odds lst (cont identity))
  (if (null? lst)
      (cont null)
      (if (odd? (car lst))
          (odds (cdr lst) (lambda (acc)
                            (cont (cons (car lst) acc))))
          (odds (cdr lst) cont))))

(odds '(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; => '(1 3 5 7)
```

Comment: the question was badly asked. they meant oddly-numbered elements, as in, by index. and they *want* it reversed.