# Scheme function that returns the odd-numbered elements from a list in reverse

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, reverse

I have to create a recursive Scheme function for my programming class that will take all the odd-numbered elements of a list, and then return them in reversed order.

I have a function for reversing a list, and another function for getting the odd-numbered elements, but can't figure out how to combine the two into a *new* function, as they both are recursive.

It has to be *one* function that doesn't call any functions other than itself. It can not call `odd` or `reverse`, and it has to have the same functionality as calling *both* would have.

Odd Function:

```
(define (odd lst)
    (if (null? lst)                   
        '()                          
        (cons (car lst)              
              (odd (cddr lst)))))
```

Reverse Function:

```
(define (reverse lst)
   (if (null? lst)
       '()
       (append (reverse (cdr lst))
               (list (car lst)))))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Lisp.

Comment: @ScottHunter Are you saying Scheme is not a Lisp? Are you saying "lisp" and "scheme" must never be used together as tags on the same question?

Comment: @ArshBallagan does `(odd '(1 2))` work for you? In what implementation? --- Also, both names ("odd" and "reverse") are more or less already taken; it' better to use some unique names for your functions, to avoid the confusion (e.g., it could be "odd-numbered-elts" and "my-reverse").

Comment: @WillNess:  'null?' isn't valid Lisp.

Comment: @ScottHunter since when? again I ask, is Scheme not *a* Lisp? [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lisp/info) does say "Lisp is a family of general purpose programming languages.......", after all. Common Lisp has its own tag. So I'd say, it's perfectly OK to have a question tagged by both [tag:lisp] and [tag:scheme], or both [tag:lisp] and [tag:common-lisp], for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reverse` mostly does what you want, except that it includes the even-numbered elements as well, in its result.

For example, if you were trying to reverse `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` with your `reverse`, it would make a *recursive call* to reverse the list `(2 3 4 5 6 7)`; if you could get it to leave off the `2` from *that* recursive call, you'd be in good shape here (although you'll have to deal with an edge case which you'll discover quickly enough).

Comment: It has to all be one function that doesn't call any function other than itself

Comment: @ArshBallagan right, and this answer gives you hints as to how this can be done.

Comment: @WillNess: To be fair, Arsh's comment was information that did not appear in the original version of the question.  (And thanks for the *'s.)

Comment: it wasn't there explicitly, yet you did get the intent! :)